# How to upgrade database with newer JPA timestamp fields?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, migration, database-migration

I have a Spring Boot application running using JPA and Hibernate to automagically manage my entities. When I created this application, I used an older version of JPA that didn't have support for Java 8 DateTime API. However, without a lot of knowledge about JPA, I used `LocalDateTime` in my entities and it worked! Not having to know about the underlying database structure was great!

Until now...

I am upgrading JPA to a version that does support `LocalDateTime`, and I am facing an error with the way JPA is using this field. It used to save this object as a `VARBINARY` (tinyblob) field in my MySQL database, but now it is smart and expects it to be a `TIMESTAMP` type. Which means that when I start my application using the configuration `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` I get the error:

```
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: 
    Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [answer_time] in table [user_answer]; 
    found [tinyblob (Types#VARBINARY)], but expecting [datetime (Types#TIMESTAMP)]
```

So now I am kinda lost on how to convert these fields to their new timestamp types. I was thinking about using FlyWay to write a migration script, but I have no idea how JPA stored the object as blob. When print a `VARBINARY` field as string this is what it looks like:

`¬í sr 
java.time.Ser]º"H²  xpw  ã
!;:;Ö@x`

This is how my entity looks like (which was unchanged during the upgrade):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_answer")
public class UserAnswer {
    private Long id;
    private LocalDateTime answerTime;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getAnswerTime() {
        return answerTime;
    }

    public void setAnswerTime(LocalDateTime answerTime) {
        this.answerTime = answerTime;
    }
}
```

How can I update my database so it converts the old `VARBINARY` fields that it used to store `LocalDateTime` data to `TIMESTAMP` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would try (after backing up the DB!) :

- Keep the old JPA API + implementation (Hibernate) versions.
- Keep the old `LocalDateTime` field.
- Add another `java.sql.Date` field to your entity. Make sure to annotate it properly  etc. so that Hibernate knows exactly how the column should be defined.
- For all entities:

  - Load each entity, read the `LocalDateTime`, convert and store it to the `DateTime` field, `merge()`.
- Remove the `DateTime` field.
- Remove the column for the old `LocalDateTime` from the table.
- Change the type of the `DateTime` field to `LocalDateTime`.
- Upgrade the JPA API + implementation (Hibernate) versions.

---

- JPA impl (Hibernate?) should store the `DateTime` as `TIMESTAMP`.
- The JDBC driver should be able to pick up the TIMESTAMP into `LocalDateTime`.

Also, consider `ZonedDateTime` rather than `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: `java.sql.DateTime` does not exists, I think you mean ` java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp`. I think I understand the approach you're trying to explain so I am trying it out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, maybe. I do not have Javadoc in my head :) But thanks for noticing, I fixed the post.